# Skip expressjs middlewares in unit test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express

I'm attempting to "skip" all of the middleware(s) in my App.ts for express.

I'm unit testing a specific route and I don't care about all of the logging / other logic that occurs in the app.ts middlewares.

It does not seem that there is a way to skip over these middlewares and instead I have to mock/stub all of the services/etc used?

Comment: can you not just add the middlewares when the environment is not ```testing```

Answer (score 0):

You may implement a logic to not attach middlewares if your environment is test, however this approach is not good as in future you might want to write some middleware which you want to test out. 
In your app.js you can list out middlewares which you want to attach in test environment then.

You can use [stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) to stubs your middleware to and assert if they were invoked or called with correct arguments.